# Puppet classes with environment directories

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet and would like to avoid some of the common issues that I see and get away from using import statements since they are being deprecated. I am starting with very simple task of creating a class that copies a file to a single puppet agent.

So I have this on the master:

```
/etc/puppet/environments/production
/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules
/etc/puppet/environments/production/mainfests
/etc/puppet/environments/production/files
```

I am trying to create node definitions in a file called nodes.pp in the manifests directory and use a class that I have defined (class is test_monitor) in a module called test:

```
node /^web\d+.*.net/ {
     include test_monitor
    }
```

However when I run puppet agent -t on the agent I get :

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class test_monitor for server on node server
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

What is the proper way to configure this to work. I would like to have node definitions in a file or files which can have access to classes I build in custom modules.

Here is my puppet.conf:

```
[main]
environmentpath = $confdir/environments
default_manifest = $confdir/environments/production/manifests
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter

[master]
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```

I know this is probably something stupid that I am not doing correctly or have mis-configured but I cant seem to get it to work. Any help is appreciated!! To be clear I am just trying to keep things clean and have classes in separate files with specific node types also in their own files. I have a small to medium to size environment. (approx 150 servers in a data center)

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, maybe the `test` module has wrong structure. You need some subfolders and files under folder `modules`

```
└── test
    ├── files
    ├── manifests
    │   ├── init.pp
    │   └── monitor.pp
    └── tests
        └── init.pp
```

I recommend change from test_monitor to **test::monitor**, it makes sense for me, if you need use  test_monitor , you need a test_monitor module or test_monitor.pp file.

```
node /^web\d+.*.net/ {
     include test::monitor
    }
```

Then put monitor tasks in `monitor.pp` file

Comment: I would vote up, but there are several points I don't understand. How can you tell that the OP's module is ill structured? Why is Hiera required? Why this specific hierarchy?

Comment: Thanks to point that, I updated my answer, because I have to guess what happen with my experience.

Comment: Still confused as to why you require the OP to install and configure Hiera, honestly. I agree that it is generally a good idea (I have gone [on record](https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/puppet-essentials) with that ;) but it does not pertain to the issue at hand in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I clear that hiera parts. Let wait OP's feedback.

Answer (score 0):

And that was as simple as adding the proper module path to puppet.conf

```
basemodulepath = $confdir/environments/production/modules
```

Comment: That's more of a workaround, really. The `environmentpath` should suffice for all regular needs.

Comment: Yes you are correct and I have removed that from my puppet.conf. It was the way I was calling the class itself that was the issue. I did restructure the module directory as suggested above since that seemed to follow the general flow of the puppet docs and made sense for this project. However Hiera is not required and I did not implement that change.